# .net/sql server creating abstract object layer architecture

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, object, orm

I have a a broad-scoped architecture question. I have multiple .net projects and multiple databases all interacting with each other across multiple web applications all for internal use. We would like to create an over-arching layer, somewhere, somehow, to create objects out of the data we query from a database. These objects would have functions/methods available to them, defined somewhere. The question is, what is the most efficient, flexible and advantages/disadvantages of way to define these objects.

For example. Let's say I have multiple HR-related tables: `tbl_employees`, `tbl_departments`. When I pull an `employee` into an application, I then have a whole bunch of code in that project that is associated with that `employee`, most predominately the functions I can do to that `employee` - functions such as  `edit_contact_info` or `increase_salary` or `add disciplinary_note`. Similar with a `department` and functions such as `edit_department`, `manage_department_employees`. Some functions may include some logic in them, some may just redirect to a particular page.

My question is, how or where or what can I make to classify an `employee` entry or even series of `employee` entries as an "object", meaning whenever I pull that "object" somewhere, I also have the associated actions with it. Whether I am pulling the data as a list somewhere or even as part of a data-visualization, I would like to have the appropriate functions/methods available. Even if it is in a different project.

I am looking for different possibilities, not necessarily one answer and I am not entirely sure the best way to go about it although I have thought maybe about creating another layer within the database that holds all the "object" definition data or perhaps some definitely with the .net framework but I lack the expertise to know *exactly* what I am talking about. From my limited knowledge, I believe I am looking for some sort of ORM (maybe in-memory) implementation, but I am not sure how to get started exactly.

Does anyone have any ideas or a direction to point me in perhaps?

I appreciate any and all help!

**Edit**
To be clear, what I am trying to find is something I can apply on top of projects and applications I already have up and running and that are being used. I would like a way to implement this over-arching `object` functionality on top of pre-existing mvc projects

Comment: One of these two will solve your problem; either an N-Tier Architecture or Onion Architecture. Given the opportunity, I would choose Onion.

Comment: @AydinAdn are there any tutorials or implementation examples of Onion Architecture you might be able to point me in the direction of? In particular, converting an existing series of applications, not starting from scratch

Comment: I faced a similiar dilemma recently and decided to go with implementing an N-Tier architecture, simply because it was easier to explain and teach. N-Tier architecture is heavily dependent on dependency inversion and if your team doesn't know / care about DI, the likelihood of it even staying an onion architecture is slim to none. Plural sight has some courses on the subject if you're interested https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/n-tier-apps-part1

Comment: thank you. I read a couple of overviews and tutorials online about the Onion Architecture but I haven't found an illustration of exactly what I am looking for. I don't quite see how then information is pulled from the database and made into objects, rather than just data. For instance, I want across all my projects to be able to write `employee.` and see all the related methods